# DC BJT Circuit Allowable collecter swing discepency

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, bjt

Im working through tutorials of BJTs from sedra smith in which the lecturer has video solutions that you can follow as you go if you get stuck.

The issue is i don't agree with some assumptions that have been made and i have checked chegg for the solution, in which there none of them obtain the solution provided via video.

The first assumption is that the BJT is in the active region. I am fine with this are working through the question will result in an answer that tells you if it is in active or not.

[image]

Now the assumption made that i don't agree with is that the lecture says that the +-1V swing at Vc (Stated in question) is equal to Vcb=-+1V. This confuses me because the question is saying that it is an allowable swing. Its not saying that the voltage difference between Vc and Vb is always going to be -+1V. Next point because active is assumed Vbe=0.7v. I agree with this. and can then conclude that Vb=0.7V which is also true. Now to solve Vc the statement Vc=Vb-+1v=0.7+1(only uses the positive swing value) is made. which i disagree with due to my initial Vcb=-+1V discrepancy. From this point on i continued through with the provided video solution to see were it went but believe that it is incorrect.

I have attached my working which is a copy of the video working

Note i did not bother with that very last part of the question regarding beta=150. Because im at the conclusion that  everything is wrong.

[image]

[image]
Im going to review chegg answers to see if i can get an understanding also

Thanks.

Comment: If the collector has to swing +/-1V about its mean, without leaving the active region, then at -1V it must not fall below the base voltage. Therefore its mean (and therefore its bias point) must be >= Vb+1V. That's all the assumption says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach the first step (\$\beta=100\$.)

Assuming (incorrectly, but who cares) that \$V_\text{BE}=700\:\text{mV}\$ when \$I_\text{E}=500\:\mu\text{A}\$ and knowing that to stay out of saturation it must also be that \$V_\text{C}\ge V_\text{BE}\$, then the only margin I have to play with is \$V_\text{CC}-V_\text{BE}-V_\text{PP}=3\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}-2\:\text{V}=300\:\text{mV}\$.

That margin can be used to keep the BJT from being turned completely off (good idea) by using some of it as a minimum voltage across \$R_\text{C}\$. But I also have to account for the fact that \$V_\text{BE}\$ itself varies by about \$60\:\text{mV}\$ for each factor of 10 change in the collector current. If I used ***all*** of it for that purpose then I'd have at most a factor of \$\frac{2\:\text{V}+300\:\text{mV}}{300\:\text{mV}}\$, or about 7.7, which is below 10. But that also says it's getting close to \$60\:\text{mV}\$ variation of \$V_\text{BE}\$, so I'd better reserve at least that much at the bottom for the minimum \$V_\text{C}\$.

So I choose to reserve \$100\:\text{mV}\$ to add to the minimum \$V_\text{C}\$, leaving the remaining \$200\:\text{mV}\$ as a minimum voltage drop across \$R_\text{C}\$.

This means I pick a quiescent \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}=700\:\text{mV}+100\:\text{mV}+1\:\text{V}=1.8\:\text{V}\$. This means that \$R_\text{C}=\frac{3\:\text{V}-1.8\:\text{V}}{500\:\mu\text{A}}=2400\:\Omega\$. That just happens to be a standard 5% value. I can also now compute \$R_\text{B}=\frac{1.8\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{4.95\:\mu\text{A}}=222\:\text{k}\Omega\$. So I'll use the nearby standard value of \$R_\text{B}=220\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

Solving the two nodal equations simultaneously (I'll leave the details of that to you):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{C}}{R_\text{B}}+\frac{V_\text{C}}{R_\text{C}}+I_\text{C}&=\frac{V_\text{CC}}{R_\text{C}}+\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_\text{B}}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_\text{B}}+\frac{I_\text{C}}{\beta}&=\frac{V_\text{C}}{R_\text{B}}
\end{align*}$$

For \$\beta=100\$, I get \$I_\text{E}\approx 502.4\:\mu\text{A}\$ and \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}\approx 1.794\:\text{V}\$. Close enough. There is room for the full swing required and this may work.

For \$\beta=50\$, I get \$I_\text{E}\approx 342.6\:\mu\text{A}\$ and \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}\approx 2.178\:\text{V}\$. Clearly, there isn't room for the up-swing. So this won't continue to provide the full swing, anymore.

For \$\beta=150\$, I get \$I_\text{E}\approx 596.3\:\mu\text{A}\$ and \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}\approx 1.569\:\text{V}\$. This time there isn't room for the down-swing. So this also won't continue to provide the full swing, anymore.

The maximum is probably \$\beta=118\$ and the minimum would be \$\beta=70\$.

Note that the above calculations do NOT take into account the expected variations in \$V_\text{BE}\$, which is assumed fixed. In reality, it would vary over a span of perhaps \$26\:\text{mV}\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{2\:\text{V}+200\:\text{mV}}{200\:\text{mV}}\right)\approx 62\:\text{mV}\$. (A full solution of the above nodal equations would require the use of the LambertW function.)

Answer (score 2):

If Vc can swing by +/- 1v, then as Vb is constant (0.7v assumption!), by definition Vcb can also swing by +/- 1v. Note this constant 0.7v assumption is false, but it's sufficiently true to be useful. If it's stated as true, then it's true for this exercise.

The next assumption to make is what collector voltage you want at DC. With a 3v power supply, the maximum collector voltage is 3v at zero emitter current (less a gnat's for Ib). Do you take as the minimum voltage 0.7v, so the current through \$R_B\$ never goes -ve, or do you take 0.2/0.3(ish), which is a reasonable \$VCE_{sat}\$? Although this would imply a negative current through Rb, so what? The only way to get collector voltages down below Vc(dc) is to be injecting an external base current from the signal input anyway, so I would argue that a negative current through \$R_B\$ is of no consequence, and Vc can go below 0.7v.

Let's assume \$Vc_{min}\$ = 0.4v. Almost any BJT ought to be able to get down here, and it allows the 3v to 0.4v = 2.6v total Vc range to easily be divided by 2 (this is my engineers' 'if a signal is not well defined, then assume it so it's easy to calculate' thang). A 2.6v swing is +/- 1.3v, so the mid point is 3v(rail)-1.3v = 1.7v, and the range 0.7v to 2.7v. Note the lower excursion of 0.7v has nothing directly to do with VBE=0.7v, it's the mid-point of Vcc and a reasonable VCEsat less a -1v signal.

For 0.5mA Ie at DC, we need 0.5mA though Rc with a 1.3v voltage drop, Rc = 2.6k. There's 1v across Rb, and we need 5uA through this, so that's 200k. You can grind through the 5% resistor and changing beta variation yourself.

Any difference between the above answer, your answer, and your book answer is down to assumptions about what the Vdc should be. When you make assumptions, they should be a) reasonable, and b) stated, like I have. Adding the justification for the assumptions doesn't hurt as well, especially if this is an exercise.

A lot of what an engineer does on the back-of-an-envelope is about making reasonable assumptions, and this is why numbers are shaded if necessary to make them easy to do without a calculator. It's better to have an approximate calculation that you understand, can find your way around, can modify easily, can understand why it's different to the 'one in the book', than to match the book solution to the 5th decimal place. Though some professors disagree, know yours.

A further comparison of our answers. Mine contains a lot of explanatory words, and very few numbers. Yours, lots of numbers and equations, without explanation. I had difficulty in following it, and so will your prof. You will in six months time.

When you come to do the beta variation, it says 'what is the allowable variation at the collector?' This is another assumption, what *is* the allowable variation? If there's no further collector load stated (what is this stage driving?), then presumably we can go all the way to +ve rail and down to VCEsat? Or do we stick at +/-1v swing. It doesn't really matter which you choose, as long as you state what you have assumed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the vcb=+-1V understanding.
I understand when you say Vcmin =0.4 giving range on2.6v but then you go on to say this puts Vc(DC) at 1.7v (midpoint for 1V swing.) do you mean 1.4v? due to the first assumption Vc=0.4? either way i understand the logic you are getting at. By picking a Vc midpoint to allow swing and stay in active region, because negative Vc swing would equal Vc at 0.7v.

thanks for you help

Comment: Hmmm, obviously not enough numbers included. No, I meant 1.7v, not 1.4v, I've added a few more numbers to bridge the gap. I didn't say 'midpoint for 1v swing', I said midpoint. One thing we do on the back of an envelope is to find the total allowable range, and then sit the signal swing right in the middle of it, because *bad things* often happen as you reach either end of the range. It's generally not good to have a required swing equal to your maximum allowable range. In this case, the *bad things* are running out of drive current through Rc near to Vcc, and losing beta near to VCEsat.

Comment: How could Vc go below 0.7V? This means current must flow in the opposite direction(from the emitter to the base).

Comment: @MohammedHisham How could the collector voltage change away from its mid-point at all? The circuit as shown has no input. Where is this +/- 1v output swing to come from? There must be an external connection applying an input current. That external connection supplies enough current that even a negative current through Rb still results in a positive base current into the transistor. You have to think carefully about what the true limits are, and what has been omitted from the diagram, what must be assumed, it's more involved than it looks.